# How to create Ear from different projects

Tags: maven, ant

I have 3 different Ant java projects like web(controller layer), service(service layer),and dao(dao layer) and all were integrated in Ant in separate project(EAR). Now I converted all projects Ant 2 maven. But I struck up in maven projects integration in EAR project.

Projects
|
|------web
|------service
|-------dao
|--------EAR

is my project directory structure.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a pom file for the EAR module:

```xml
<project...>
  <parent>
  ..
  </parent>

  <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>...</groupId>
      <artifactId>mod-web</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>...</groupId>
      <artifactId>mod-service</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

If you have done everything well just via `mvn clean package` should procues and ear file in `mod-ear/target/` folder.

Comment: +1 -- Also, be sure to include maven ear plugin and other standard dependencies for successful build and packaging.
Reference : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html

Comment: You don't need to include it explicitly cause it's bound by default [for the life-cycle](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html). Only to make it better pin the version of the maven-ear-plugin in your company or parent pom.